# iOS location permission from whenInUse to Always

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I would like to upgrade my application location permissions from whenInUse to always.

As per documentation, requestAlwaysAuthorization() API does the job.
The problem here is -

It asks prompt only if use never rejected always permission. Also this can be done only once.

Is there any way, I can identify that requestAlwaysAuthorization() fail to show prompt because of above reason?

Possible solution:
I can store user decision into UserDefaults when app first ask for permission and accordingly I will get to know how it will behave for second time.

Is there any other way to check whether prompt has been presented or not.

Note: locationManager:didFailWithError: doesn't do this job. I have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need:

```
    func isLocationServiceAvailable() -> Bool {

        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Here I can still ask for upgrade if status is authorizedWhenInUse. Problem is I can only ask if ever user doesnt rejected authorizedAlways (and choose authorizedWhenInUse for second time)

Comment: I would like to know requestAlwaysAuthorization()  this API has not prompted or not prompted dialogue.

Comment: unfortunately AFAIK, if the user ever rejected the location permission, you cannot determined later if the requested permission was .whenInUse or .always.

Comment: Yes we can't determine whether Prompt has been shown by apple or not ( due to any reason ) .. any workaround to get to know this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the two things one is OS level and another one is App level location service enabled or not.

> For OS level using below variable you can manipulate the value in
>   userdefaults

```
var osLevellocationServicesEnabled: Bool {
        return CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    }
```

> For appLevel using below variable you can manipulate the value in
>   userdefaults. For instance if user reject permission to always then
>   using below variable you can update the value in userdefault yes/no
>   accordingly and then based on that you can prompt custom alert to the
>   user asking to update the location settings manually

```
var appLevelLocationServicesEnabled: Bool {
       return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt resolve my issue... I would like to know requestAlwaysAuthorization() this API has not prompted or not prompted dialogue. If it prompted I would like to do some tasks and if not i would like to do some other tasks...

Comment: @user3647675, The thing is if you turn off your OS location setting. Then OS will not prompt you dialogue again. You need to handle it manually.

Comment: Scenario I am talking is assuming OS location setting is ON

Comment: That is the iOS level popup and it controls by OS. But after dismissing OS level pop up you can check whether OS location service is on or Off. And then you can customize your code.